# Qt App is able to access database in development machine but not on target machine

Tags: windows, qt, sqlite, qt4

I have this app that uses sqlite database. Login to the app is done by accessing the credentials in a table in the database. I am able to login on the development machine but on the target machine, i am not able to login. I built the program in release mode. What could be the problem?

target machine is windows 7, no debug info or warning.
These are the files i shipped with the app;

**kernel32.dll**
**libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll**
**libstdc++-6.dll**
**libwinpthread-1.dll**
**msvcrt.dll**
**QtCore4.dll** 
**QtGui4.dll**
**QtSql4.dll**
**the_database_file.db**
**user32.dll**

Comment: are there any debug infos - like some error messages? how do you deploy on target machine? what OS host/target? you provided very little infos..

Comment: I have updated my question. The program runs on the target machine but i am not able to login.

Comment: Ist the sql dll in the `sqldrivers` subdirectory? I am not sure if this is required with qt4 as well but it is often forgotten and not always necessary on a dev machine as qt finds it in its own path

Comment: Where is `.sqlite` file with DB located? And how did you write path to it in code ?

Comment: Why are user32.dll, etc. included? My nose tells me something there is responsible.

Comment: @Bowdzone do you mean i should create a directory in my exe folder called 'sqldrivers' and put the  sqlite driver in it? i don't get you

Comment: @JonHarper i run dependency walker and it showed i am supposed to add user32.dll

Comment: Try deleting user32.dll and kernel32.dll. Those are core libraries and will already be available to the application. There are any number of reasons this might be a problem and just as many that it might not. It's worth a shot.

Comment: @JonHarper Thanks for that, i deleted those files, the app still runs ok but i still am not able to login. I've seen an answer, let me try that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a folder in your executable directory called **sqldrivers** and add sqlite driver plugin to it. I think it should be;
**qsqlite4.dll** You'll find the driver plugin in **Qt\4.whatever\plugins\sqldrivers** 
You should be able to login or access the sqlite database on the target machine now. I think Bowdzone was trying to say the same thing.